# Java ternary operator (?:) doesn't work; second or third operand return boolean

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Can someone tell me why this use of the ternary operator is incorrect? Operands 2 and 3 return a boolean.

```
public class Something {
...
private static final double REFERENCE_FRAME_MID_X = 0;
private static final double REFERENCE_FRAME_MID_Y = 0;

private boolean findInsideOrOutsideGeneralEllipse(Point2D destCirclePos) {
    List<Boolean> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    Point2D referenceFrameCenter = new Point2D.Double(REFERENCE_FRAME_MID_X, REFERENCE_FRAME_MID_Y);
    Ellipse2D insideAreaEllipse2D = getEllipse2D(referenceFrameCenter.getX(), referenceFrameCenter.getY(),
                                                    destCirclePos.distance(referenceFrameCenter));

    // doesn't work
    insideAreaEllipse2D.contains(destCirclePos) ? returnValue.add(true) : returnValue.add(false);

    // works
    if (insideAreaEllipse2D.contains(destCirclePos)) {
        returnValue.add(true);
    } else {
        returnValue.add(false);
    }
}
...
}
```

Comment: I can't even tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: you just want,   `returnValue.add(insideAreaEllipse2D.contains(destCirclePos));`

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Did you get any exception, error?

Comment: @nachokk I know it can be done that way, but I'd like to understand exactly why that is a compile-time error...

Comment: @deinocheirus. You need to tell what compiler error you get, else we can only guess.

Comment: conditional operator does not exist to conditionally execute the expressions, but rather to conditionally return the (non-void) result of one of the expressions.

Comment: ternary operator must be used for assignment, otherwise you will get a compiler error.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  The result of `add` is not the added value, but a boolean indicating whether or not the collection changed.  The value of the expression will always be true, since the empty collection has a value added to it (either true or false).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A ternary expression does _not_ need to be used as the right hand side of an assignment;  it's an expression, and can be used any place that an expression can be used.  See the comments on [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010504/1281433).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usage of Java ternary operation condition should looks like

```
result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

it's java-language specification.

[*Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> In the following example,
>   this operator should be read as: "If *someCondition* is *true*, assign the
>   value of *value1* to result. Otherwise, assign the value of *value2* to
>   result

Comment: I can't speak as to why you got downvoted, but there's no requirement that the result of a ternary expression be used as the right hand side of an _assignment_.  `condition ? val1 : val2` is an _expression_, and while it can't be used as a statement, there are lots of places you can use expressions, not just assignments.  E.g., you could `System.out.println( condition ? val1 : val2 );`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor your code is equivalent to `String s = condition ? val1 : val2; System.out.println(s);`. It's the same that I said

Comment: Yes, and you _can_ do `String s = "Hello" + " " + "World!"; System.out.println(s);` instead of `System.out.println( "Hello" + " " + "World!" );`, too, but that doesn't mean that the latter is what your code _should_ look like.  Sometimes it make sense to assign the value of expressions of variables, and sometimes it makes sense to use them directly.  Just because you _can_ do `variable = condition ? val1 : val2` doesn't mean that the only place that a ternary expression should appear is the right hand side of an assignment.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor note that you're already passing the result of `condition ? val1 : val2` into a temporary variable that will be used in `System.out.println( ... )`. Try just having `condition ? val1 : val2;` with nothing on the left side. If you make it work, let us know to email James Gosling about this :).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Joshua is talking about the places where you can use conditional operator. And it's not only in assignment context. The usage of `?:` as argument to method, is not an assignment context, but a method invocation context.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm aware that the conditional expression isn't a _statement_.  My point is that an _expression_ can be used in other places than an assignment.  [Rohit Jain's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010424/1281433) quotes the specification about the grammar, and makes this clearer.

Comment: Citing the Java tutorial is a good point, and the code there is `result = someCondition ? value1 : value2;`.  It's not just the `someCondition ? value1 : value2` expression that's being read that way, but rather the whole assignment.  The Java tutorial a bit sloppy on that point.  A better way of phrasing it would be "assign to `result` the value of the following: if `someCondition` is true, then the result of evaluating `value1`, otherwise the result of evaluating `value2`."

Answer (score 5):

From [JLS - Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> In fact, by the grammar of expression statements (§14.8), it is not permitted for a conditional expression to appear in any context where an invocation of a void method could appear.

Grammar of [expression statements from JLS - 14.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons:
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>       StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>        Assignment
>        PreIncrementExpression
>        PreDecrementExpression
>        PostIncrementExpression
>        PostDecrementExpression
>        MethodInvocation
>        ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```
>
> An expression statement is executed by evaluating the expression; if the expression has a value, the value is discarded. Execution of the expression statement completes normally if and only if evaluation of the expression completes normally.
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language allows only certain forms of expressions to be used as expression statements.

Now the way you are using the conditional operator is not a valid expression statement, as inferred from it's grammar. And hence you get the compiler error. You have to use it in any of the above mentioned context.

Comment: I have explicitly pointed out that returnvalue.add() returns a boolean.

Comment: @deinocheirus The point isn't that the types of the expressions aren't compatible, but that the ternary operator expression (the conditional expression) _isn't_ a _statement_, but an _expression_, and in your code it appears in a place where a _statement_ is expected.

Comment: @deinocheirus Yes, but your code still isn't a *StatementExpression*.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor he edited his answer to the point my comment no longer makes sense.

Comment: @Axel the same thing :)

Comment: @deinocheirus. Sorry for not adding a comment after editing. Didn't notice those comments earlier.