# In Java What Does This Mean "length >= 0 ? length : length * -1"

Tags: java

I am learning Java and have a simple question.

In an example of setting a class I see this:

```
length >= 0 ? length : length * -1
```

What does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ternary operator (?:) doesn't work; second or third operand return boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010399/java-ternary-operator-doesnt-work-second-or-third-operand-return-boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a hackish way of writing [`Math.abs(length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29). It calculates the absolute value of the `length` by using the [Conditional Operation ?:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (per the JLS)

> The conditional operator ? : uses the boolean value of one expression to decide which of two other expressions should be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` is the Java ternary operator. See http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Essentially it has form:

```
[condition] ? [execute if true] : [execute if false]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is `ternary operator` in java.

```
ifTrue ? thanThis : otherwiseThis
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a ternary expression. If the value before the question mark is `true`, the expression equals the first value after the question mark (`length`). If the value before the question mark is `false`, the expression equals the value after the colon (`length * -1`).

Answer (score 1):

this is Java ternary operator, it means

```
if(length>=0) {
     length = length;
} else {
     length = length * (-1);
}
```

Comment: its good you expanded this to an if statement except in your example you reassign length. perhaps change this to return.